# Play Framework 2.0 multiple static routes

Tags: scala, routes, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set up two different static asset routes, and the second one fails.  What am I missing?

To duplicate the issue:

1. start with the hello world from the scala samples.
2. add a line to routes, so now there are two static routes:

   ```
   GET     /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
   GET     /assets2/*file      controllers.Assets.at(path="/public2", file)
   ```
3. comment out the Assets references in main.scala.html, so it doesn't complain about them
4. put a file in public and public2.

   ```
   $ cat > public/foo.txt
   hi
   $ mkdir public2
   $ cp public/foo.txt public2
   ```
5. verify that the public dir works.

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 9000
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   GET /assets/foo.txt HTTP/1.0

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Content-Length: 3
   Content-Type: text/plain
   Etag: 5246040afe91a4cc93bd838a4d5db3984b99470b
   Cache-Control: no-cache

   hi
   Connection closed by foreign host.
   ```
6. verify that the second one doesn't work.

   ```
   $ telnet localhost 9000
   Trying 127.0.0.1...
   Connected to localhost.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   GET /assets2/foo.txt HTTP/1.0

   HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
   Content-Length: 0

   Connection closed by foreign host.
   ```

I'm sure there's something obvious here, I"m just not seeing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add `public2` folder to `playAssetsDirectories` in sbt config

```
playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "public2"
```

See [PlaySettings](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/PlaySettings.scala) as an example.

Comment: i added a little to the wiki, to save future generations some time.  https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Assets

Comment: Could you be more specific about how PlaySettings would help?
PlaySettings does not have strings "playAssetsDirectories" or "baseDirectory /" in it. Thanks